# Disable Google Toolbar Autocomplete in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, html

Although an [Autocomplete question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field) was asked last year, I wanted to see if there was a solution that worked in both IE and FF that disabled the Google Toolbar Autocomplete.

A [Google employee](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Toolbar/thread?tid=7dcddc95f43dac19&hl=en) suggested they will release support for the autocomplete="false" attribute, but it appears it will just be for FF.

Update:
 - I haven't found a solution to this problem, the autocomplete="false" doesn't work in the current version of the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

Force the user to uninstall Google Toolbar.

How you can do that, I'm not sure.